# How to design "Following" relations with Redis

Tags: redis, relationship

I am trying to the implement a scenario when user A is following users B so all follower's of user A will follow User B as well.

For example:

Assume we have 4 Users( users:1 users:2 users:3 user:4)

-> indicates 'following'

User2->User3,User4

New Action:
User1->User2

I want to update all followers of user:2(aka user:1) to follow user 3 and user 4 aswell:

Expected results

User1->User2,User3,User4

User2-> User3,User4

I need this behaviour on all users

I started to think about my solution. please let me know how to actually fit that in.

I am using sets where the key is the [unsername]_followers.
Each time user has new follower I am going to retrieve his follower list and iterate on the code one by one and modify their list by adding to it the new user.

the problem starts to get abit complicated because I also need to update followers of followers

code:

```
requirement fact: if a follow b, b must follow a

//creating new users:

HMSET user:110 username rot
hMSET user:111 username jane
HMSET user:112 username kenny

//adding follow relations:

//user 110 started to follow user:111
sadd user:110_following user:111
sadd user:111_following user:110


//user 112 started to follow user:111
sadd user:111_following user:112
sadd user:112_following user:111


//update other "influenced" followers:

127.0.0.1:6379> smembers user:111_following
1) "user:111"
2) "user:110"
3) "user:112"

//need to update 110 (since 110 follows 111 which follow 112)
sadd user:110_following user:112

127.0.0.1:6379> smembers user:110_following
1) "user:111"
2) "user:110"
3) "user:112"

//need to update 112 (since now 110 also follows 112)
sadd user:112_following user:110
```

What do you think about that way?

Thanks,
ray.

Comment: You should use sets. BTW, I still think you want someone to give you the entire solution. You should put some effort before asking, and then you should ask something more concrete...

Comment: You right. I actually started to think on solutions but they dragged me into complicated logic. Anyway I modified my answer with candidate soltuion. Thanks for your support.

Comment: "because I also need to update followers of followers" - that's the very thing you're after, isn't it?

Comment: Yes right. was jus saying it's started to get complicated within my solution

Comment: @rayman Define "complicated". At the end of the day, Redis is a key-value store. Sometimes you need to perform 4-5 operations to implement a transaction...

Comment: @rayman Why don't you rephrase your question from the scratch pasting here your current code to check your approach with actual code??

Comment: added some redis code

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer I wonder if you had a chance to look at my modified question with the code. thank you.

Comment: @rayman Added an answer ;P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all, your approach is fine. There're some issues anyway:

1. Don't store `user:x` (where `x` is the user id) in sets but store just `x`.
2. Use `:` separator: `users:11:followers`.
3. Maybe you should create a sorted set too. I guess you want to list followers in some order. Store both in sets and sorted sets in order to be able to do set operations like intersections and pagination too (f.e. `zrange`).
4. When you're storing data in more than a key, you should use `multi` commands to perform this operations atomically.
5. Maybe you want to store JSON objects instead of storing data in many hashes. For example: `hset users 1 { "userName": "Matias" }` instead of `hset users:11 username Matias`. Since you're going to perform mostly all operations using `list`, `set` and `sorted set` commands, there're few reasons to store each user property in hashes.
6. Instead of retrieving all followers in your application layer, [why don't you use `sunionstore`](http://redis.io/commands/sunionstore)? This way, if you union user A followers with user B followers, and you store the result in user B followers, since it's a *set*, resulting set will only contain unique user ids.

Comment: Thanks for your response.about point 5. I read it will be better in memory to store on hashses also will be easier for me to retrive specific fields. why do you suggest using jsons in the value? And another thing. As you can see I need to iterate on each user followers and update them. that might take along time on the code side. isnt there any efficient way to do this? I am expecting lots of read/write of this following model. around 1000 reads/writes per sec.

Comment: @rayman You use hashes if you need to access these specific fields. Also, it's not bad idea to redound data. If you need to list objects you get their JSON representations, while when you need to get a particular field, you access the per-property, per-user hash

Comment: @rayman About the thing of using `smembers` I don't understand at all... If you already know what followers you added, why you need to get them and then add later?

Comment: Thats exactly the problematic thing. as soon as user a is following user b. user a should also follow the users that user B follows. so i am checking with smembers the users that user b's follow and modify each memeber on that list by adding user a as their new follower aswell( if B follows C and A now follow B outcome-> A follows B and C

Comment: @Matais, I am not sure if you understood my last comment. if not I would try to clarify it

Comment: @rayman my laptop died yesterday. I'll try to analyze your comments un The next days.....

Comment: @rayman So you want to add the users which follows A to B, and users follwed by B to C and so on. Yes, there's a better solution than `smembers`!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @rayman Check the sixth point I've added today as an update to my answer and let me know if it solves the issue with `smembers` ;)

Comment: Ahh cool! you were great. I apologise for not pasting my code in first place!

Comment: @rayman Now you've saved your API from performing a lot of loops with `sunionstore`!